# If Else Condition not Working in Increase and Decrease Value of qty

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to Disabled the image view when the value is zero.
I tried a lot but don't know where's the problem is.

And in the other Activity this code is working perfectly but when I paste this same code in ListViewAdapter of listView's then it is not working

The Problem I'm facing is:-

When I run the application first time then it is working perfectly but when I do the same thing again then decrease ImageView is disabled.

and the second problem is when I move down to the page then it will directly show 0 and when I increase then it will give me the last qty.

Don't know where's the problem is here, the complete code is as follow:-

**listViewAdapterorder.java**

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView mname , pmethod2, pamount3, premark4;
            final ImageView increase,decrease;
            final Button add;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) cntx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cntx);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_order, parent,
                    false);
            decrease = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrease);
            increase= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.increase);
            add= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);

            mname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mname);
            mname.setText("  " + o_aproduct.get(position));


            final TextView displayInteger = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.integer_number);
            //add.setText("  " +count);



            increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int count = sia.get(position);
                    count= count + 1;
                    sia.put(position, count);
                    displayInteger.setText("" + count);
                    add.setText("  " +count);
                }
            });
            decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int count = sia.get(position);
                    count= count- 1;
                    sia.put(position, count);
                    displayInteger.setText("" + count);
                    add.setText("  " +count);
                    if (count > 0 )
                    {
                        decrease.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else if (count == 0 ){
                        decrease.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                    else {
                        decrease.setEnabled(false);
                    }


                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: What is sia and where is it defined?

Comment: As a total sidepoint: Why are you inflating your layout all the time? You should be reusing the one received if it is not null. Inflating a new one and then performing findViewById is a massive overhead.

Comment: sia is  SparseIntArray() and it is defined under public ListViewAdapterorder(Context context, and       sia = new SparseIntArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't run your code, but it seems a bit odd that there's no `decrease.setEnabled(true);` line in the increase button's click handler. This means that when increasing the number past zero again, the decrease button won't get re-enabled. Is this what you want?

Comment: if (count > 0 )
                    {
                        decrease.setEnabled(true);
                    }

Comment: if the 0 is there in TextView then its remain disabled or else it will enabled

Comment: @WealInfotech That's in the decrease button handler, which makes no real sense since the decrease button is disabled. If it was in the increase button handler the code would probably work better, although I'm not 100% certain what the OP's desired behaviour is.

Comment: thnq it is working now but when i moved down to the listview and came back on first ListView's item then it will showing me 0 when i increase the value then it is showing me the last value.

Comment: So I guess when you scroll away from it the TextView displayInteger is discarded and forgets its value, so what you need to do it reload its value from `sia` when it comes back into view. I'm afraid I don't know how to do that; you might want to open a new question for this part of the problem.

Comment: exactly and thnq so much for the help..   :)

Answer (score 0):

> When i run the application first time then it is working perfectly but
>   when i do the same thing again then decrease ImageView is disabled.

You should `clear` the count, because application knows the last result.

And for second issue `clear` will work too.

Comment: @ where i clear the count in the imageView click Lisnter only or somewhere else??